# Get all table names of a particular database by SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on application which can deal with multiple database servers like "MySQL" and "MS SQL Server".

I want to get tables' names of a particular database using a general query which should suitable for all database types. I have tried following:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

But it is giving table names of all databases of a particular server but I want to get tables names of selected database only. How can I restrict this query to get tables of a particular database?

Comment: For Mysql you can do simple.   SHOW TABLES;

Answer (score 663, accepted):

Probably due to the way different sql dbms deal with schemas.

Try the following

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG='dbName'
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
```

For Oracle I think the equivalent would be to use `DBA_TABLES`.

Comment: I prefer this solution when I have different table schemata within one database (SQL Server):
SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG='MyDB'

Comment: One must be using that particular **DB** to get the information.
`USE dbName GO` for SQL-Server. If you're not using the **DB**, result will not be displayed, even if there are tables in that DB.

Comment: For Mysql you can do simple.   SHOW TABLES;

Comment: The SQL Server entry works fine for me without the `USE dbName GO` prefix on Server 2014.

Comment: 1) You have suggested the same thing for an SQL Server and MySQL
2) INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES exists only in MySQL
3) I really wonder how comes you got so many upvotes for this ...

Comment: This is the correct answer!  SHOW TABLES is just an overlay for querying the actual information schema.  SHOW TABLES fails when you want to select tables from a single DB.

Answer (score 105):

Stolen from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/26/sql-server-2005-list-all-tables-of-database/):

```
USE YOURDBNAME
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Comment: Most probably   SELECT Name FROM sys.Tables where is_ms_shipped = 0

Comment: this is database provider specific, and not ANSI SQL compatible.

Comment: Alternatively, SELECT * FROM yourdbname.sys.Tables; if you prefer to be more concise. Works in SQL Server, at least.

Comment: Careful with using sys.Tables, you can end up with multiple names because you are not taking into account the schema. Two tables exactly the same name with different schemas will show twice

Answer (score 42):

The following query will select all of the `Tables` in the database named `DBName`:

```
USE DBName
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Comment: NO it only Part seperator. you can change to other.Its not an T-SQL syntax.

Comment: USE DatabaseSample SELECT * FROM sys.Tables

Answer (score 20):

Just put the `DATABASE NAME` in front of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:

```
select table_name from YOUR_DATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 19):

```
USE DBName;
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables;
```

We can deal without `GO` in-place of you can use semicolon `;`.

Comment: For SQL Server on Azure, this worked for me, but the accepted answer didn't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

In mysql, use:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

After selecting the DB with:

```
USE db_name
```

Comment: Osm,,, swt n short

Comment: This is MySQL, question is tagged wit MSSQL server

Comment: @Melle Look at the description of the question

Comment: This is not the best answer, see my comment under the accepted (and correct ) answer.

Answer (score 12):

In order if someone would like to list all tables within specific database without using the "use" keyword:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM databasename.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: You will get all the table by using above query, If you want to just get table which is in public > table . Then add
 `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM postgres.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_schema = public`
Remember using postgres

Answer (score 11):

## This works Fine

SELECT
*
FROM
information_schema.tables;

Answer (score 7):

I did not see this answer but hey this is what I do :

```
SELECT name FROM databaseName.sys.Tables;
```

Answer (score 7):

To select the database query below :

```
use DatabaseName
```

Now

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Now you can see the created tables below in console .

PFA.

[image: Query]

Answer (score 4):

For Mysql you can do simple.   **SHOW TABLES;**

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from sys.tables
order by schema_id      --comments: order by 'schema_id' to get the 'tables' in 'object explorer order'
go
```

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate a bit on what you mean by this? Maybe explain it?

Answer (score 2):

In our Oracle DB (PL/SQL) below code working to get the list of all exists tables in our DB.

```
select * from tab;
```

and

```
select table_name from tabs;
```

both are working. let's try and find yours.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM your_database_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Exec sp_MSforeachtable 'Select ''?'''
```

Comment: Hi Amirreza, I believe you are talking about `sp_MSforeachtable` ?

Comment: @bummi: yes great,Thank you for attention and sorry for typing mistake. Edited

Answer (score 1):

```
USE dbName;

SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName' OR TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaName')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

If you are working with multiple schemata on an MS SQL server, then SELECT-ing TABLE_NAME without also simultaneously selecting TABLE_SCHEMA might be of limited benefit, so I have assumed we are interested in the tables belonging to a known schema when using MS SQL Server.

I have tested the query above with SQL Server Management Studio using an SQL Server database of mine and with MySQL Workbench using a MySQL database, and in both cases it gives the table names.

The query bodges Michael Baylon's two different queries into one that can then run on either database type. The first part of the WHERE clause works on MySQL databases and the second part (after the OR) works on MS SQL Server databases. It is ugly and logically a little incorrect as it supposes that there is no undesired schema with the same name as the database. This might help someone who is looking for one single query that can run on either database server.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE FOR THE LATEST VERSION OF MSSQL SERVER (17.7)**

```
SELECT name FROM sys.Tables WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```

Or `SELECT *` for get all columns.

Comment: I just realized that this query give wrong result for non-english characters in table name while Michael Baylon's gives correct results. (character was in Turkish language lowercase "ı" )

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes oracle is :

```
select * from user_tables
```

That is if you only want objects owned by the logged in `user/schema` otherwise you can use `all_tables` or `dba_tables` which includes system tables.

Comment: they're looking for cross provider queries not provider specific.

Comment: There is no consistent way to do this from sql as all db engines implement the data dictionary differently. It might be possible to abstract this using jdbc/odbc and a 3GL language such as C/Java/C# if this is a programmatic requirement, definitely possible if you have a different implementation for each database. The op should clarify their requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Building from Michael Baylon's answer, I needed a list which also included schema information and this is how I modified his query.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME as 'Schema.Table'
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'dbName'
  ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get all improtanat information with this below SQL in Mysql

```
    SELECT t.TABLE_NAME , t.ENGINE , t.TABLE_ROWS ,t.AVG_ROW_LENGTH, 
t.INDEX_LENGTH FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as t where t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOURTABLENAMEHERE' 
order by t.TABLE_NAME ASC limit 10000;
```

Answer (score -1):

for postgres it will be:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema  = 'your_schema' -- probably public
```