# DSN-Less Connection with multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba, dsn

Right now I have an MS SQL database with about 50 or so tables in it with which I'd like to link to MS Access using a DSN Less connection. Below is the basic code where I have a parameter of stRemoteTableName which is the table name of the SQL table to import. I could call this function each time for each table but that would take forever; is there anyway to loop through all tables in an SQL database and pass them to this function so that all tables are imported? I'm having a very hard time finding any code online for something like this, so help is much appreciated.

```
 Private Sub ImportAllTables(stRemoteTableName)
        On Error GoTo AttachDSNLessTable_Err
            Dim td As TableDef
            Dim stConnect As String
            stServer = "C:\Location"
            stDatabase = "DB"
            stLocalTableName = stRemoteTableName
            stUsername = ""

            For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
                If td.Name = stLocalTableName Then
                    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stLocalTableName
                End If
            Next

            stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"

            Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, stRemoteTableName, stConnect)
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
            Exit Sub

        AttachDSNLessTable_Err:

           AttachDSNLessTable = False
            MsgBox "AttachDSNLessTable encountered an unexpected error: " & Err.Description
        End Sub
```

Comment: You can query for all the table names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pass-through query to list the table names from your SQL Server database.  Open a recordset based on that query.  Then loop through the recordset rows and link each table.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strConnect As String
Dim strSelect As String

strSelect = "SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t;"
'strConnect =  <you already have this as stConnect>
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSelect)
qdf.Connect = strConnect
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        ' you want to link; I will just list
        ' the table names
        Debug.Print !name
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
Set rs = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm always learning, only going into my junior year of college and the only programming I've done is VB and VBA (very limited).

Comment: You're welcome.  Most of that is fairly standard Access VBA.  Pass-through queries seem to be less familiar to many people AFAICT.  Did it all make sense to you?

Comment: Yes I'm understanding it better now that I'm seeing your code and looking at some of the stuff on MS support, but I'd have to agree with you; I've never had to deal with pass-through queries even though I've heard of them.