# Microsoft Access System Data Source disappears seemingly at random

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc

I have set up a System Data Source in Microsoft Access, and it works great while it is connected. For some unclear reason, over the course of 3 weeks I have seen it disappear from this list about 4 or 5 times. When this happens, the linked tables become inaccessible and Data from the SQL server we are connecting to becomes unavailable.

The only resolution is to go back into the External data tab and create a new data source from an ODBC database with the same parameters as before. Then everything is functional again, but it shouldn't be unlinking to begin with.

I also have the ODBC Data Sources administration application installed to this machine, however System DSNs that I create in there for some reason do not show up in Access, regardless of whether they are 32 bit or 64 bit. The Data sources created here have never disappeared.

For clarity, this is the latest O365 version of Microsoft Access. ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. This is a virtual terminal server.

I thought it could be a reboot causing issues, however it has disconnected multiple times when the uptime was over 21 days. Then recently I rebooted the machine and the System DSN did not immediately disappear.

I've tried creating DSNs in 32 bit and 64 bit version of ODBC administrator. None of these ever show up in MS Access.

The SQL server is hosted by a 3rd party host, so there is nothing I am immediately able to change on that side.

Comment: You can make your life easier by using DSN-less connections. No DSNs needed in Windows at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536205/dsn-less-connection-with-multiple-tables