# Find all tables whose name ends with a certain suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, information-schema

I have thousand of tables in database. Some names end with `_History`.

For example :

```
abc_History
bcd_History
123_History
```

How do I find all tables which name is end with `_History`.

Some thing like:

```
SELECT
table_name
FROM sys.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '_History%'
```

And

```
error : Invalid column name 'table_name'.
```

Comment: question mark should be before %_History

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_History'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '%_History'
```

Comment: I added DISTINCT as there were duplicates in the TABLE_NAME

Comment: In oracle, it is FROM ALL_TABLES or ALL_ALL_TABLES. Just thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Saharsh-shah.

To **get table name with all column names** in the same query, use this :

```
SELECT 
    `TABLE_NAME`,
    group_concat(`COLUMN_NAME` separator ',') AS `COLUMNS`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` IN(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
        WHERE `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%_History'
    )
GROUP BY `TABLE_NAME`
```

You can push it in multidimensional PHP array very simply with the following :

```
$tables['columns'] = explode(',', $tables['columns']);
```

Hope it can help some.