# How to identify the table name from last insert or update in sql server and mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In sql server and mysql
I want a query to identify the tables name which are affected using INSERT or UPDATE

Additional info:
 1. I have more than two tables and all tables may not have indexes.
 2. If a stored procedure execute I don't know what are the tables inserted or updated. But here I want to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL server

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'AdventureWorks')
AND OBJECT_ID in (select OBJECT_ID(name) from sys.tables)
ORDER BY last_user_update DESC
```

not sure about MYSQL

taken from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query)