# How to get data source information from WSO2 DSS?

Tags: wso2, datasource, wso2-data-services-server, dataservice

Usually, we will use WSO2 DSS to config a data source and issue data service based specified data table. How would I get the related data source information about configured data source, including: data-source name, table names, and column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that's what you mean but I'll give it a go:
In: wso2dss-installfolder\repository\deployment\server\dataservices\
You will find the data services you have configured as .dbs files, it's actually just an xml that contains all the information.

EDIT:
From [Get all table names of a particular database by SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query) I found that this MS SQL query will give you the names of all your tables in YOUR_DATABASE:

select table_name from YOUR_DATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

Comment: At present, I hope get the data source service, rather then data serivice. In other word, I would get data base information, and get the table names and data structure from database or data source.

Comment: Ok, after a quick search I found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query

It's a SQL that gives you a list of all the tables in your MS SQL database: 

select table_name from YOUR_DATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
Then you can search what SQL query is needed to retrieve column names