# How can I find tables name of selected database in MsSql

Tags: sql-server, database

I want get tables name of specific Database in MsSql without

```
using db-name
```

something like this in mysqlIi need

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema=db-name
```

how  I can do it?

Comment: i found  it : SELECT * FROM myDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all table names of a particular database by SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Table_schema` use `Table_catalog` and you can prefix the `DB-name` before `information_schema` to get the tables in that database

```
SELECT *
FROM   [db-name].information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_CATALOG = 'db-name'
```

Comment: I think he needs to find the table list based on database filter. so using "[db-name]." nullifies the usage of where condition

Answer (score 0):

```
Use UR_DBNAME

SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the shortest version of what your are looking for

```
select name from [db_name].sys.tables
```