# How to properly retrieve table ID

Tags: sql-server

According to the database theory, any table inside a database is successfully identified by using its fully qualified name, `catalog_name.schema_name.table_name`.

In SQL Server a way to retrieve the table id is:

```
SELECT object_id(table_name);
```

Should I use the fully qualified table name from the first sentence as a parameter to this query? If not - how the engine will know what table I'm requesting this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the same database as the object, you can use schema qualified name. 
E.g., `Schemaname.ObjectName`

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'Production.WorkOrder') AS 'Object ID';  
GO
```

If you are in different database, as against the object database, you have to use fully qualified name of the object. E.g. `DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName`

```
USE master;  
GO  
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder') AS 'Object ID';  
GO
```

Basically, it retrieves information from `sys.objects` catalog view and returns the object identifier. You can read more about this: [object_id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: it says 261575970. What is the data type? int or bigint or something else?

Comment: It is INT as specified in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

- First, Look in the “sys” schema , then
- Look in the active default schema, then
- Look in “dbo” schema.
- If schema name is specified, SQL server simply looks in the designated schema.

An old but still relevant article on name resolution in SQL Server:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/04/03/name-resolution-default-schema-implicit-schema-part-i/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/04/03/name-resolution-default-schema-implicit-schema-part-ii/

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose in sqlserver have a Master database in which all other database and its all objects entry in there and it store in system tables.

For each object in the master database is define from `Object_ID`, there are different tables. Sys.objects is the table which has all the entry which differ via type (like U- User defined, T -

There are various ways you can find all table names present in a database by using following system or metadata tables in SQL server (refer [Quara link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-SQL-query-to-find-all-table-names-present-in-a-database))

Each tables you can access from `catalog_name.schema_name.table_name`

Here is

> catalog_name - is your database name
>
> schema_name  - is your user / Schema name(for access rights, by default its dbo and have all permission)
>
> table_name  - is your actual table name

[How can I find tables name of selected database in MsSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018870/how-can-i-find-tables-name-of-selected-database-in-mssql)

Anything start from `Sys` in db is the reserve and system object either table or view or procedure or else.