# Properly retrieve table ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228906/how-to-properly-retrieve-table-id) says that the info is retrieved from `sys.objects` view. However this view has only table name field for the schema it has schema_id.

Does it use a self relation for that `object_id()` function or it queries some other system table/view
to get the schema name?

I can't use object_id() directly, since my code of:

```
std::string query = "SELECT object_id(?)";
```

fails with the error because binding parameter is prohibited inside the `SELECT` clause of the query.

So I need to write the actual query to retrieve it.

Could someone please help?

Basically I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT object_id from sys.objects WHERE name = <table_name> AND schema = <schema_name>.
```

However, I don't see where can I get the `schema` field...

EDIT:

It looks like the correct query will be

```
SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects o, sys.schemas s WHERE s.schema_id = o.schema_id AND o.name = <table_name> AND s.name = <schema_name>
```

but trying to run it Management Studio I don't get any rows.

Comment: object names (table, procedure, column, etc.) cannot be parameterized. You will need to build **carefully** the query to include the qualified name of the object you are interested in.

Comment: Added an explanation of what I'm after... Apparently not everybody understands the notion of `schema_name.table_name` or `fully qualified table name syntax`.

Comment: @SMor, do you know how?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Firstly the value passed to the object_id function can be a parameter and there is no prohibition in using them there. secondly what input are you trying to get the object id for? If you know both the table name and schema name you can use them with that function and pass a two part name. If you don't know them it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: @MartinSmith, no, it can't. Using `SELECT obect_id( ? )` and trying to bind the table name in my c++ program fails because parameter can't be part of SELECT. So now what I'd like is to have a SELECT query just like the one in my edit - problem is I don't know what field I should use for schema_name.

Comment: @MartinSmith, the actual call that failed was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldescribeparam-function?view=sql-server-ver16.

Comment: If isn't going to be able to infer anything automatic about the desired datatype if you use it there. You would need to tell it that that parameter has a datatype of nvarchar(256) and not call that function. I don't use that API but presumably via SQLBindParameter

Comment: @MartinSmith, does `nvarchar` supported by all DBMSes? Or its MS SQL Server only?

Comment: `nvarchar` is unicode string so will probably be as `SQL_WVARCHAR` in ODBC. The `object_id` function itself is only relevant to SQL Server

Comment: @MartinSmith, I understand. I'm trying to write cross DBMS software and already have queries for other platform. Only SQL Server is a miss.

Comment: @MartinSmith, please see my last edit.

Comment: First off, don't use old-style `JOIN`s, just write `FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id`. Second, by "schema", do you by any chance mean "database"? Some DBMSes use this term to mean "database", but SQL Server does not; instead objects are contained inside schemas which are contained inside databases. If you get no results, then either your object name/schema name are incorrect (take care that they are not escaped or quoted), or you're in the wrong database.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I believe in MS SQL schema means `user`. And what I want is to supply full qualified table name to get the object id. In regards to your first comment - I understand that this query will run on MS SQL Server and I should use `JOIN` MS-ism. But when working with multiple DBMSes it is easier to write the code compatible to basic standard.

Comment: No, schema doesn't mean user -- it used to, but it hasn't meant that since SQL Server 2000, where users and schemas were decoupled. Regarding the "basic standard" -- calling `JOIN` an MS-ism is exactly the wrong way around. Old-style joins are what isn't the standard (at least not anymore) -- `JOIN` is ANSI SQL, to be specific ANSI-92, and you'll be hard-pressed to find any RDBMS today that doesn't support this syntax, if they support joins at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, IIUC, it was MS who promoted the JOIN syntax and pushed to remove ANSI standard. But that aside - do you see anything wrong with the query I posted? Or you so used to the new syntax, you can't work with ANSI standard? ;-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, just for completeness - I tried with JOIN syntax and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

So, the last query I posted is correct.

The problem was I needed to issue:

```
USE db_name;
```

because apparently even though my ODBC string contains DB nameI had to explicitly issue "USE" command.