# SqlCommmand parameters not adding to UPDATE statement (C#, MVC)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sqlcommand

If you look at the stuff commented out, I can easily get this to work by adding user input directly in to the query, but when I try to parameterize it, none of the values are being added to the parameters...

This code is throwing an error

> Must define table variable @formTable

but the issue is none of the values are adding, not just the table variable (verified by replacing table name variable with static text).

I have many insert statements in this project structured exactly like this one which work perfectly. What am I doing wrong here?

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    //string query = "UPDATE " + s.formTable + " SET " + s.column + " = '" + s.cellValue + "' WHERE MasterID = '" + s.id + "'";
    string query = "UPDATE @formTable SET @column = @cellValue WHERE MasterID = @id;";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        //SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@formTable", s.formTable);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formTable", s.formTable);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", s.column);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellValue", s.cellValue.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", s.id.ToString());

        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are for values, not object identifiers (tables, columns, etc.), so the only valid parameters you have are `@cellValue` and `@id`.

If you want to dynamically set table/column names based on user input, you're likely looking at string concatenation.  *However*, that doesn't necessarily mean SQL injection.  All you need to do is validate the user input against a set of known values and use the known value in the concatenation.

For example, suppose you have a `List<string>` with all of your table names.  It can be hard-coded if your tables are never going to change, or you can make it more dynamic by [querying some system/schema tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query) in the database to populate it.

When a user inputs a value for a table name, check if it's in the list.  If it is, use that matching value from the list.  If it isn't, handle the error condition (such as showing a message to the user).  So, even though you're using string concatenation, no actual user input is ever entered into the string.  You're just concatenating *known good values* which is no different than the string literals you have now.