# Get tables names of a specific database selected by user from combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I am working in visual studio to get the database names in SQL server and in obtaining those I am successful.But now I want to fill a combobox with the tables names of a database that is selected by user from another combobox. Here is what I have tried so far when I run the application the combobox for table names is filled for the Database that I have mentioned in the query.But it should depend on the user that if he selects any database from combobox then the table names for that database should be populated in table names combobox. So the user must not mention explicitly the name of database in query.

Basically it should pick the name of selected database from combobox and populate another combobox with respected table names.

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM 
RegistrationFrom.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'", 
con))
{
                using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add((string)reader["TABLE_NAME"]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: RegistrationFrom is the name of the database, you just need to replace it to the value of your first combobox.

Comment: @BrunoQuintella I can get the current selected item which is databse name from combox in a string but I don't know how I should replace that string value in query here.. can you write query again.

Comment: Maybe you should use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` and change the connection string before each query to the selected database.

Comment: If i understood what you want correctly your querry must be: `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM 
RegistrationFrom.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='<Selected Database Name>'`

Comment: @BanForFun Thank you but I want it something like this. SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM combox.Text INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'.......combox.Text contains the database name

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin Then the anwser that BrunoQuintella is what you want. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes something like this...but let me check if it works..

Comment: WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @paparazzo   WinForms

Comment: Then you should tag is such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all table names of a particular database by SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query)

Comment: @paparazzo it doesn't uses any value from a combo box in query....which is basically the problem here

Comment: If you just need the selected value from a combobox then why even mention the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170227/discussion-between-zain-ul-abidin-and-paparazzo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace **RegistrationFrom** to the value of your first combobox.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder myQuery = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
myQuery.AppendFormat("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM {0}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'", valueOfCombobox);

using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(myQuery.ToString(), con))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add((string)reader["TABLE_NAME"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of tables you can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [master].[sys].[databases]
```

You will need to filter to remove the system *databases*, probably excluding owner_sid 0x01 is your best option. Now that you have that dump it into your combobox. Hook in to the selection change on that combobox and run your current query dumping the list it to combobox 2.