# How to show all created tables in SQL Developer by sql statement?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Show tables;
or
 Show all tables;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all table names of a particular database by SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to fetch the result.

```
select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'your_database_user';
```

Comment: It gives all the table from the database but I want to know only created all the table which one I have created.

Comment: If you have your own user in db, its possible to fetch only the tables you created. Else its not possible

Comment: Own User means.?      Bcz I have only one user SYSTEM

Comment: You cannot fetch the table names created by you particularly. You can fetch only be meance of user you created

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables
```

Alternatively, if you do not have access to DBA_TABLES, you can see all the tables that your account has access to through the ALL_TABLES view:

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
```

or

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
```