# List ONLY the SQL Server tables that my app uses (the ones in the "Tables" treeview in SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am having trouble figuring out how to just get a list of tables that show up in the SSMS treeview under dbname->tables. I don't want the system tables, and I don't want any views, etc. I ONLY want the tables that show up under the tables view in the treeview. I tried this:

```
Select * from dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 Where dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

But that gives me more than just what is in the treeview under Tables. The problem I am trying to solve is that there are over 7000 tables in there and I have a proc to "hide" the ones I never look at, but I need to apply it in bulk to ONLY the list in the Tables list where row-count = 0. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Please don't get too distracted by what I am ultimately trying to do... That is just for context. The main question is "how do I just get the list of tables under the "Tables" treeview for a specific database."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all table names of a particular database by SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query)

Comment: @Rafaqat Ali Still returns more than expected. Again, try it against MSDB to see 147 rows returned when only 7 are expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, void of any answers that gave me what I needed, I did the following:
In SSMS, I selected the "Tables" node in the treeview for the database in question. Then I hit the "F7" key, which displayed a list of the tables in the "Object Viewer". That list included the tables under the "System Tables" as well (which I didn't want), of which there were only two. The good news is that the Object Viewer allows multi-select, so I just selected all the tables, copied them (CTRL+C) and pasted them into Excel. Then I just deleted the two tables I didn't want from the resulting list in Excel. Not as elegant as an all code/SQL based solution (which is what I was aiming for) but since this is a one-off I can live with it. If I had been okay with getting the "System Tables" as well, then the SQL from my original question seems to be the best answer, although @Lamu 's use of the "IS_MS_SHIPPED = 0" was an interesting angle that anyone reading this should take a look at as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE YOURDBNAME
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Comment: Nope. Try that on the MSDB table (which shows only a handful of tables in the treeview (7 in my case) but the query you provided returns over 100 tables.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query

stack overflow question? Details are provided on the provided link. You may check that.

Comment: But `msdb` is a **system** database, @JesseChunn ; it won't (shouldn't) have any user tables in there.

Comment: @Lamu The point is... SSMS somehow knows which tables to show in the treeview under the "Tables" branch. How does it know?

Answer (score 0):

Seems what to op is *actually* after is:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.[type] = 'U';
```

But, of course, the fact that you have user tables in a system database is different problem.

Comment: I do not have user tables in a system database. I have a database that is part of an application that we use. That database has more than 7000 tables. I want to get the list of tables that are under the "Tables" tree in the SSMS treeview. Anything else I have said is strictly intended to help explain what I am trying to do. I do not want any of the tables under "system tables" or any store procs or any views or anything else. JUST the tables listed directly under the "tables" branch. Sorry if that is confusing, but I don't know how else to say it.

Comment: The above statement completely contradicts your previous comment, @JesseChunn : *"Again, try it against MSDB to see 147 rows returned when only 7 are expected."*. `msdb` is a **system** database.

Comment: @Lamu Sorry if I am not able to explain in a way that makes you (and others) understand.. The MSDB is provided as an EXAMPLE because it is a database that YOU will have on your SSMS instance that WE have in common for TESTING and comparing results. You do not have my 7000+ table database, so I merely provided MSDB as a common denominator between us to compare results. I am not putting user tables in MSDB. It is not relevant that it is a system database for this "test". Anyway, I came up with a cumbersome but effective method to get what I needed.

Comment: *"You do not have my 7000+ table database"* No, unfortunately one of my databases has a mere 20,000~ objects, @JesseChunn ... But saying that you see 7 tables in `sys.tables` when you expect 7 very strongly infers you're expecting to see user tables only. Unfortunately, as a result, you give us no where near enough information for us to give an answer to you.

Comment: Okie dokie. You win. Yours is bigger than mine.