# Searching sql database for a certain table from a user input

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a way to search a database so that if a user puts in an input such as a Username, then it would go through the database and look for the same exact name of a table, in C#?

Example:
if A input was Test, then it would search the database for a table that has the name Test.

Comment: Are you asking how to [Get all table names of a particular database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query)?

Comment: Or perhaps you're asking [How to directly execute sql query in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709305/how-to-directly-execute-sql-query-in-c)?

Comment: I am asking how to search threw a database for a table with the same exact name as the user input. for example User input = test, and a table in a database = test

Comment: You should read through the links I provided. They will get you exactly that. It may require some reading and piecing together, but that's expected because you are actually asking about how to do multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is sql server, your tables are all in sys.tables, so this will do it...

```sql
select * from sys.tables T where T.name = @searchTerm
```

Search your conscience, though. There is generally no good reason to have a query like this in your app code. Your code is where you commit yourself: a named table, a selection of columns.

Comment: Very similar to the suggested [Get all table names of a particular database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query). The top answer there with a simple `WHERE name = @tableName` would do it. This is basically a duplicate question.